# In InDesign, is it possible to make tables flow to new pages as you insert more tables?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, tables

I have a multi-page document with lots of separate tables on each page.  I want to be able to insert new tables into the middle of a page, so that the tables below it are then 'pushed' onto the next page (and all following pages with tables are also pushed).  Is this possible? [image]

Comment: I don't get it. Because you say it already consists of multiple tables, at least 5 by my count, I don't quite understand why you would ask how to add another one. Like did you forget how you added the 5? — Are all the tables inside separate text frames or something?

Comment: @Joonas it would appear as though each table in the sample image is its own text frame... I think that's where the issue lies - separate text frames.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely possible, you just need to make sure your entire content runs as linked (threaded) text frames, then each time a new table is needed just insert that into the same multi-page text frame flow.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ij8aFNIKsl8
- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/threading-text.html
- https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/creating-tables.html